# How can I call rehydration(persist/REHYDRATE) manually inside Component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I am using redux-persist in my React Native app.

What I am going to do is to clean redux store when logout from the app.

```
persistStore(
  store,
  {
    whitelist: compact([
      'appInfo'
    ]),
    storage: AsyncStorage
  },
);
```

I know redux persists only the states in whitelist.

Therefore, I want to call this function when I logout from the app to clean the previous users details from redux store.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Many thanks,

Comment: I am looking for the same, did you find a good solution in the meantime? It is a classic when a user logins into a react native with different accounts

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `userDetails` to whitelist key?

You don't need to call `persistStore` everytime you want to persist store locally. It is meant as one time setup call ideally right after you `createStore` using redux.

On logout you can trigger an action `USER_LOGGED_OUT`, handle that in your reducer to clear out `userDetails` key. It will automatically be persisted then.